# Is Pazuzu from "The Exorcist" a fallen angel or a demon god

Tags: character, the-exorcist

Is Pazuzu from the horror movie "The Exorcist" really the same demon god in Ancient Assyrian mythology or is he just a typical Judeo-Christian fallen angel? I kind of find it weird that the two completely different universes of Christianity and Ancient Assyrian mythology are mixed together in a Christian supernatural horror type of movie. I am asking this because many people seem to think of Pazuzu as a demon god.

Comment: There is only one [Pazuzu](https://futurama.fandom.com/wiki/Pazuzu)...

Answer (score 3):

I researched a lot, but I could not find any reference of Pazuzu being mentioned as a fallen angel in Bible. Yes, Pazuzu might have been in the Old testament (with Bible being said to have been inspired from pagan religions) , but without his name being mentioned directly.

According to [Ancient.au](https://www.ancient.eu/Pazuzu/)

> Pazuzu is believed to have gone through at least two major
>   mythological changes. Aside from being a bird and a demon-god, though,
>   it's also possible that he made an appearance in the biblical Old
>   Testament. King Solomon faced a wind demon while attempting to build
>   the Temple Of Jerusalem. After capturing this pesky spirit, Solomon
>   learns that its name is Ephippas.
>
> According to the Old Testament, Ephippas damaged the land and killed
>   people daily with his fierce winds. This has some similarities to the
>   legend of Pazuzu, a demon that controlled the wind and could cause
>   massive amounts of death and devastation.

Comment: Maybe the creators of "The Exorcist" were inspired by the Judeo-Christian tradition of making pagan gods into demons. Like for example, Baal and Moloch. Those two were actually pagan gods until they got turned into demons. After that, the creators of "The Exorcist" decided to make a fallen angel with the name of the pagan god Pazuzu as the main antagonist that the two priests have to battle. That's just my theory. Ancient jews have a habit of borrowing from cultures around them when it comes to demons. Like for example is Lilith who is actually Lamashtu from Mesopotamian mythology.

Comment: @DavidCamden according to many people who don't believe in pagan gods, the demons were worshiped by ancient people, fearing them to be gods because of their powers. Similarly, pagans believe that their gods have been turned into demons by Abrahamic religions, as they don't have multiple gods. Thousand mouth, thousand stories. Movie makers just tend to pick whichever they find more interesting

Comment: If you’re willing to work this hard to find an answer, then watch *The Exorcist 2* because it goes into depth about the surviving priest pursuing Pazuzu. You might get an in-universe answer out of it. Warning, tho: it’s John Borman’s worst film.